# How to compare URLs in python? (not traditional way)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python, I used == to check if 2 URLs are the same, but to me, the following are the same too:

https://hello.com?test=test and https://hello.com?test22=test22

https://hello.com and https://hello.com#you_can_ignore_this

Is there any build-in function instead of working hard to compare every char etc...

Comment: Why exactly are the first two the same? Is there any way to tell that they are the same without following the links?

Comment: why aren't they the same?

Comment: The second one has "22" at the end of each test while the first does not, therefore the urls are different.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `urllib` to parse the URLs and only keep the initial parts you want (here keeping scheme+netloc+path):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url1 = urlparse('https://hello.com/?test=test')
url2 = urlparse('https://hello.com/?test22=test22')

url1[:3]
# ('https', 'hello.com', '/')

url1[:3] == url2[:3]
# True
```

Comparing only the netloc (aka "domain"):

```
url1[1] == url2[1]
```

As you can see, once you have parsed the URL you have a lot of flexibility to perform comparisons.

Comment: Since `'https://hello.com'` is essentially `'https://hello.com/'`, `url1[:2] == url2[:2]` is a better way to compare.

Comment: @DYZ depends on the use case, but yes that it a possibility (I actually hesitated to add it, will do)

Answer (score 0):

Using `urlparse` is the way to go, as suggested in another answer. However, special treatment should be used for the URLs that have an empty path or the path consisting only of the root "/", because they refer to the same document.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url1 = urlparse('https://hello.com/?test=test')
url2 = urlparse('https://hello.com')

result = (url1.path in "/" and url2.path in "/" and url1[:2] == url2[:2])\
         or (url1[:3] == url2[:3])
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not very clear what you mean, but you should try parsing the url first.

You could check it using `urlparse()`.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
url = urlparse("https://hello.com?test=test")
```

Since the `urlparse` method returns a ParseResult:

```
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='hello.com', path='', params='', query='test=test', fragment='')
```

You can compare these by doing

```
url[1] == 'hello.com' #Index 1 = netloc
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html